# HTML - ReactJS: How to shown an image inside a <div>

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using [Contentful](https://www.contentful.com/) as external container for my images.
I am building a boat visualizer using [AISHub](https://www.aishub.net/api). All the vessels I am interested are injected into a table. When I click on the table I locate the marker (vessel) on the map and the image of that vessel pops up on a sidebar on the right of the map.

**The problem** I have is that I should also visualize the image of the vessel, but unfortunately I only visualize a weird icon as shown below:

[image: map]

Below the code I have so far:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Card, CardTitle, CardSubtitle, CardText, CardBody, CardImg } from 'reactstrap';
import '../components/SideBar.css';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import Client from '../Contentful';

class Sidebar extends React.Component {
    state = {
        ships: []
    };

    async componentDidMount() {
        let response = await Client.getEntries({
            content_type: 'cashmanCards'
        });
        const ships = response.items.map((item) => {
            const { name, slug, type, company, description, images, companylogo } = item.fields;
            return {
                name,
                slug,
                type,
                company,
                description,
                images,
                companylogo
            };
        });

        this.setState({
            ships
        });
    }

    getFilteredShips = () => {
        if (!this.props.activeShip) {
            return this.state.ships;
        }

        return this.state.ships.filter((ship) => this.props.activeShip.name.toLowerCase() === ship.name.toLowerCase());
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="map-sidebar">
                {this.props.activeShipTypes}
                <pre>
                    {this.getFilteredShips().map((ship) => (
                        <Card className="mb-2">
                            <CardImg />
                            <CardBody>
                                <div className="row">
                                    {/* <div className="column"> */}
                                    <img className="image-sizing-primary" src={ship.companylogo} alt="shipImage" />
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <img className="image-sizing-secondary" src={ship.images} alt="shipImage" />
                                </div>
                                <CardTitle>
                                    <h3 className="thick">{ship.name}</h3>
                                </CardTitle>
                                <CardSubtitle>{ship.type}</CardSubtitle>
                                <CardText>
                                    <br />
                                    <h6>Project Details</h6>
                                    <p>For a description of the project view the specification included</p>
                                </CardText>
                                <div class="btn-toolbar">
                                    <SpecsButton />
                                    <Link to="/vessels/Atchafalaya" className="btn btn-primary">
                                        Go to vessel
                                    </Link>
                                </div>
                            </CardBody>
                        </Card>
                    ))}
                </pre>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Sidebar;
```

**EDITS:**

```
class Sidebar extends React.Component {
    state = {
        ships: []
    };

    async componentDidMount() {
        let response = await Client.getEntries({
            content_type: 'cashmanCards'
        });
        const ships = response.items.map((item) => {
            const { name, slug, type, company, description, images, companylogo } = item.fields;
            return {
                name,
                slug,
                type,
                company,
                description,
                images,
                companylogo
            };
        });

        this.setState({
            ships
        });
    }

    getFilteredShips = () => {
        if (!this.props.activeShip) {
            return this.state.ships;
        }

        return this.state.ships.filter((ship) => this.props.activeShip.name.toLowerCase() === ship.name.toLowerCase());
    };


    {this.getFilteredShips().map((ship) => (
        console.log(ship);

        return (
            <div className="map-sidebar">
                        <Card className="mb-2">
                            <CardImg />
                            <CardBody>
                                <div className="row">
                                    <img className="image-sizing-primary" src={ship.companylogo} alt="shipImage" />
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <img className="image-sizing-secondary" src={ship.images} alt="shipImage" />
                                </div>
                                <CardTitle>
                                    <h3 className="thick">{ship.name}</h3>
                                </CardTitle>
                                <CardSubtitle>{ship.type}</CardSubtitle>
                                <CardText>
                                    <br />
                                    <h6>Project Details</h6>
                                    <p>For a description of the project view the specification included</p>
                                </CardText>
                                <div class="btn-toolbar">
                                    <SpecsButton />
                                    <Link to="/vessels/Atchafalaya" className="btn btn-primary">
                                        Go to vessel
                                    </Link>
                                </div>
                            </CardBody>
                    </Card>
            </div>
        )))}
}

export default Sidebar;
```

**EDITS 2**:

```
class Sidebar extends React.Component {
    state = {
        ships: []
    };

    async componentDidMount() {
        let response = await Client.getEntries({
            content_type: 'cashmanCards'
        });
        const ships = response.items.map((item) => {
            const { name, slug, type, company, description, images, companylogo } = item.fields;
            return {
                name,
                slug,
                type,
                company,
                description,
                images,
                companylogo
            };
        });

        this.setState({
            ships
        });
    }


    getFilteredShips = () => {
        if (!this.props.activeShip) {
            return this.state.ships;
        }

        return this.state.ships.filter((ship) => this.props.activeShip.name.toLowerCase() === ship.name.toLowerCase());
    };

    {this.getFilteredShips().map((ship) => {
        console.log(ship);
      render() {
        return (
          <Card className="mb-2">
              <CardImg />
              <CardBody>
                  <div className="row">
                      {/* <div className="column"> */}
                      <img className="image-sizing-primary" src={ship.companylogo} alt="shipImage" />
                  </div>
                  <div>
                      <img className="image-sizing-secondary" src={ship.images} alt="shipImage" />
                  </div>
                  <CardTitle>
                      <h3 className="thick">{ship.name}</h3>
                  </CardTitle>
                  <CardSubtitle>{ship.type}</CardSubtitle>
                  <CardText>
                      <br />
                      <h6>Project Details</h6>
                      <p>For a description of the project view the specification included</p>
                  </CardText>
                  <div class="btn-toolbar">
                      <SpecsButton />
                      <Link to="/vessels/Atchafalaya" className="btn btn-primary">
                          Go to vessel
                      </Link>
                  </div>
              </CardBody>
          </Card>
        )
      }
    })}
}



export default Sidebar;
```

Below a print screen on how [Contentful](https://www.contentful.com/) is structured:

[image: contentful]

**What I have done so far:**

1) I was able to implement the table click event as well as finding the marker (vessel) and show its card on the right of a sidebar, and thought that it would have been easy to finally show the vessel image. Unfortunately the implementation does not show the image. 
I should mention that I used [reactstrap Cards](https://reactstrap.github.io/components/card/).
Maybe there is an error in how Contentful is reading the image?

2) After researching more this problem I came across [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32053687/how-to-load-image-on-canvas-and-put-markers-on-click) which was useful. The problem was that the image uploaded was local, I have an image that is external on an external container.

Thanks for pointing in the right direction.

Comment: ship.companyLogo and ship.images are undefined or url doenst work thats why its showing the broken image Icon and the text "shipImage" is there because it's the altText shown when image doesnt load

Comment: @GeneSy, thanks for reading the question. How do I fix that? Maybe `console.log` somewhere? if so, where?

Comment: Since you're already rendering maybe just add {ship.companylogo} before the image so you can see the value. or you can also right click inspect element the image to see what is passed to img src

Comment: If you really want console log output you'll have to rewrite your map() function there to instead be a normal function that returns the component and `console.log(ship)` before returning it

Comment: Thanks :) , can you also please answer posting some code? I don't understand where should I put what you are suggesting.

Comment: added an answer. hope it works for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here you go

```
import React from 'react';
import { Card, CardTitle, CardSubtitle, CardText, CardBody, CardImg } from 'reactstrap';
import '../components/SideBar.css';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import Client from '../Contentful';

class Sidebar extends React.Component {
    state = {
        ships: []
    };

    async componentDidMount() {
        let response = await Client.getEntries({
            content_type: 'cashmanCards'
        });
        const ships = response.items.map((item) => {
            const { name, slug, type, company, description, images, companylogo } = item.fields;
            return {
                name,
                slug,
                type,
                company,
                description,
                images,
                companylogo
            };
        });

        this.setState({
            ships
        });
    }

    getFilteredShips = () => {
        if (!this.props.activeShip) {
            return this.state.ships;
        }

        return this.state.ships.filter((ship) => this.props.activeShip.name.toLowerCase() === ship.name.toLowerCase());
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="map-sidebar">
                {this.props.activeShipTypes}
                <pre>
{this.getFilteredShips().map((ship) => {
  console.log(ship);

  return (
    <Card className="mb-2">
        <CardImg />
        <CardBody>
            <div className="row">
                {/* <div className="column"> */}
                <img className="image-sizing-primary" src={ship.companylogo} alt="shipImage" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <img className="image-sizing-secondary" src={ship.images} alt="shipImage" />
            </div>
            <CardTitle>
                <h3 className="thick">{ship.name}</h3>
            </CardTitle>
            <CardSubtitle>{ship.type}</CardSubtitle>
            <CardText>
                <br />
                <h6>Project Details</h6>
                <p>For a description of the project view the specification included</p>
            </CardText>
            <div class="btn-toolbar">
                <SpecsButton />
                <Link to="/vessels/Atchafalaya" className="btn btn-primary">
                    Go to vessel
                </Link>
            </div>
        </CardBody>
    </Card>
  )
})}

                </pre>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Sidebar;
```

Comment: Thanks, I am getting [this strange error](https://i.imgur.com/6GUycJN.png) of unexpected token but don't know why. I think I did everything correct, I edited the question

Comment: It's because of the previous comments. that's not how you comment on jsx. you need to use {* *} instead of //

Comment: Unfortunately same exact error but don't know why. I posted **EDITS** on the question or [here](https://i.imgur.com/AmqTYqi.png). I thought I did everything correctly but don't know why this strange thing is happening.

Comment: i can see straight away you didnt copy my answer. (ship) => { << is a curly brace. and also close with curly brace

Comment: I am sorry I posted the wrong print screen! the correct one is [this one](https://i.imgur.com/mBWWYbB.png) with the same error. sorry I didn't want to confuse you.

Comment: the render() method is now missing, you removed too much code.  from your initial code, just paste what i did over the part where `this.getFilteredShips().map((ship)` starts

Comment: Ok I copied/paste your answer and correctly kept the `render()` function that was missing. But unfortunately I have the same error, I updated the question adding **EDITS 2**. I triple checked everything now but don't understand why I have that same error. Any idea?

Comment: unfortunately you're still copying it wrong.. revert to your first pasted code. then find the part where `this.getFilteredShips().map((ship)` starts. thats where you should paste my code. my code should overwrite this part.

Comment: Yes that is what I did on **EDIT 2**, I went back to the original and copied/paste your code, but keeping the `render()` function I erroneously erased. I am committing a mistake I can't see. Could you please edit your answer with the initial post of my code but adding your answer? That would help me understand what I am missing :)

Comment: ok edited my comment. you'll just have to reindent it back. but that's how it should be

Comment: Ok :) I got lost in a glass of water! I see what I was doing wrong! Thank you very much!